# How to perform same query on two different tables in one query

Tags: mysql

First query:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM (`videos`)
WHERE  `name`  LIKE '%Dragon Ball Z (U.S.)%'
```

and second

```
SELECT `vid_id` as id
FROM (`other_names`)
WHERE  `name`  LIKE '%Dragon Ball Z (U.S.)%'
GROUP BY `vid_id`
```

All i want get is list of unique ids by `LIKE`.

Comment: definition of the two tables? are they related with a foreign key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 'and second' with 'UNION'. :)

```
SELECT `id`
FROM (`videos`)
WHERE  `name`  LIKE '%Dragon Ball Z (U.S.)%' 
UNION
SELECT `vid_id` as id
FROM (`other_names`)
WHERE  `name`  LIKE '%Dragon Ball Z (U.S.)%'
```

`UNION` (as opposed to `UNION ALL`) already returns unique items only, so you won't need `GROUP BY` or `SELECT DISTINCT`. You could write `UNION DISTINCT` if you think it's more clear, but you can omit it, since it is the default behaviour of `UNION`.

Comment: @GelozTrol Union would not remove duplicated from query, such that Query 1 return duplicate, while Query 2 are distinct, and if you union the two, anything query 1 and query 2 overlapped will be removed, But the duplicates within query 1 will remain. Correct me if I am wrong on that. I think that is the reason for UNION DISTINCT vs just UNION

Comment: @Churk Have you tried that? There is no difference between `UNION` and `UNION DISTINCT` as I described. Only if you don't want to remove duplication, you will need to use `UNION ALL`, but @aTei explicitly asked for unique ids. Take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: @Churk I just tested this, and it is correct, a `UNION` will remove duplicates from the final resultset, including duplicates that are internal to one of the subqueries.

Comment: I try this query, but get '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;'. Why can it be?

Comment: Got the reason - brackets around table name